# Dataframe indexing in a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a problem with my loop.

My goal is to write a row from my dataset in another Dataframe
I will look for the indexes of the indexes to be fetched via KNN.

```
def NaerestNeighbor_Point(Cluster, dataset, centroide):
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, algorithm='auto').fit(dataset)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(centroide)
    tab = pd.DataFrame([])
    print(indices)
    for i in range(0, Cluster):
        if i == 0:
           tab = pd.DataFrame(dataset.iloc[indices[i]])
        else :
           tab.append(dataset.iloc[indices[i]])
    print(tab)
```

Here are my results

```
[[ 51]
 [116]
 [ 63]
 [ 89]]

Sum_Power  Max_Power  Var_Power
51  220.53626   3.516042   0.432914
```

Why does my dataframe only have one row and not four ?

Thank for you help

Comment: I'm assuming NearestNeighbors() is a function you created. Can you show it?

Comment: And also, if you are referring to the 2D array, then your data frame does have four rows (and one column).

Comment: How about if you use `tab.loc[len(tab)] = dataset.iloc[indices[i]]` instead of whole if-else condition?